# Bottlenecks in a time-stamped graph

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a directed weighted graph. In addition each edge $e$ has a time-stamp $t(e)$.

A *route* $\pi$ from $s$ to $t$ is a directed walk from $s$ to $t$ with increasing time-stamps.

We are also given two sets of vertices $S$ (source) and $T$ (destination).

We associate with each route $\pi$ one of the edges $e$ with the following properties:

1. $e$ belongs to $\pi$,
2. There is no route to $e$'s head from any other source $s' \in S$ with time-stamps smaller than $t(e)$,
3. $e$ has minimum weight among the edges satisfying the conditions in 1 and 2.

Let's the edge corresponding to a route its bottleneck.

Given $G$, $S$, and $T$,
we want to compute the list of bottlenecks for all routes in $G$ from $S$ to $T$,
i.e. we want a least of the form $(s,t,e)$ where
$s\in S$, $t\in T$, and $e$ is the bottleneck edge for some route from $s$ to $t$.
We don't need all possible bottlenecks for a route but just one of them,
and it is better if the set of bottlenecks we get is minimal.

#### Questions

I am looking for references on algorithms for this or similar problems.

Does this problem have a name?

Comment: Are the edges or the vertices weighted?

Comment: I'm not sure it solves your bottleneck problem, but there are some algorithms for this sort of time-monotonic path in "Windows into relational events: data structures for contiguous subsequences of edges", M. J. Bannister, C. DuBois, D. Eppstein, and P. Smyth, SODA 2013, pp. 856-864, arXiv:1209.5791.

Comment: @András, the edges.

Comment: Since the weights are both on the arcs, it seems easier to move to the vertex-weighted line digraph.  One can then intersect the DAG with the poset (actually, transitive tournament) implied by the timestamps.  What remains is a vertex-weighted DAG in which every directed path is a route.  The properties are then about activity-on-node networks (task graphs), and it seems $e$ is a minimum weight vertex among the critical vertices on route $\pi$.